# is it possible to manually call a click on a dom object?

Tags: javascript, events, addthis

I am using addthis and they have a bunch of obfuscated code that I am loathe to dig through in their embedded javascript.  I would like to "click" one of their buttons on my page without the user having to touch it.

So, in essence, there is a `<a>` that contains their button (which their embedded javascript handles when the user clicks it).  I would like to "click" it for them, via my own javascript, but don't see anything like a native "clickMe()" function associated with the anchor tag object.

Is it possible to do this, or is it missing from the spec due to security concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this turns out to be a problem where every solution looks like a hammer, as we examine the problem assuming it's a nail.

The way to do this (and it's 100% cross browser) is simply to redirect the page to whatever addthis has set as the href to the link.

In otherwords...

```
self.location.href = document.getElementById("addThisFbLink").href;
```

That's all there is to it.

@kooilnc, I appreciate your solution, it wasn't what I needed, but in a way it led me to figuring this out, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the AddThis code more carefully and their functionality is have an `onclick` handler for the parent `div` of each `a`. If you know the `id` of the `div` you want to click, just put it in this line. As a back up, you can also try `click()` for the `a`.

```
var id = 'atic_facebook'; //for example
document.getElementById(id).onclick();
```

Comment: hmm... how the hell did I miss THAT?!

Comment: @Niklas I tested it, works with Firebug: `document.getElementById('atic_facebook').onclick();` but only when it is not set to `display:none`

Comment: @js1568 it redirects the user to facebook?

Comment: awarded the checkmark prematurely.  click is not a recognized function on the A tag and onclick() works in chrome, but not in webkit or safari.... back to the drawing board :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a function to programmatically fire an event on a DOM element:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
   if (el.fireEvent) {
     (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
   } else {
     var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
     evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
     el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
   }
}
// usage
eventFire(document.getElementById('someHref'),'click');
eventFire(document.getElementById('someElement'),'mouseover');
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the "onclick" function of an element directly:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i;
for (i=0; i<as.length; i++) {
  if (as[i].onclick) {
    as[i].onclick(); // Run the "onclick" function.
  } else if (as[i].href) {
    window.location = as[i].href; // Browse to the URL.
  } else {
    // Not much we can do!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery trigger():

> Description: Execute all handlers and
>   behaviors attached to the matched
>   elements for the given event type.

```
$('a').trigger('click');
```