# Programatically click on cell in ui-grid to get into deep edit

Tags: angular, dynamic, click, cell, ui-grid

On beginCellEdit in ui-grid, I would like to programatically click on the cell to get into deep edit.  Is there a method that would let me do this in the beginCellEdit eventhandler ?

My beginCellEdit is shown below.

```
 gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {

//method to invoke the click action

});
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Deep edit is initiated by clicking on the cell that is already in edit mode.

This will be a dirty workaround at best, but it appears to work.

You will need a piece of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298114/2442813), plus a way to get the element you want to click.
I have ui-grid-cellNav enabled, so my cell has class: `'ui-grid-cell-focus'` Also i'm using jQuery since i have it loaded anyway.

```
$('.ui-grid-cell-focus').parent().find('form').children()[0]
```

I select the cell, then i get its parent, find a form element inside it and select the first child element inside that in hopes it'll work with more than just plain input boxes.

Here is the whole thing.

```
function eventFire(el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
} 

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        eventFire($('.ui-grid-cell-focus').parent().find('form').children()[0], 'click');
    });
};
```